# How can you view the commit history of a single branch in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, commit

I have searched this site, google, and pycharm's website. I can't figure out how to view the local commit history of a branch in Pycharm.

Edit: I am using the latest version of Pycharm for Mac, and Git for VCS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't specified the version of PyCharm, so I'll assume you're using somewhat fresh (2017.1.3), as well I'll assume you're using Git.

At the bottom of the PyCharm window select `Version Control` (<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> shortcut is default). Next, select `Log` at the top of created window. You should see a list of commits. Now you can click `Branch` at the top and filter by specific branch.

[image]

Comment: @Eddy, please accept the answer (and vote), so others would see that this question has been answered. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the tips, just accepted the answer. I also voted but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation for it to display my vote.